# How to start the first ConfigNode of Apache IoTDB cluster version after clearing data?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

The first ConfigNode of Apache IoTDB cannot be started now after I cleaned all historical data, and there is no log updated. The error message is `ERROR o.a.i.c.c.s.SyncConfigNodeClientPool:108- REGISTER_CONFIG_NODE failed on ConfigNode TEndPoint(ip:master1,port:10710)`. I already shut down all processes in IoTDB but the progress still fails. Anyone know what more do I need to do start this ConfigNode?

Answer (score 0):

If the data stored in older confignode of Apache IoTDB is no longer needed, then all nodes in the IoTDB cluster must be cleaned first and then the nodes can be restarted. You can check: 1. if you clean up ALL the confignode/datanode process. You can use `kill -9 <pid>` to kill processes if you cannot close them normally. 2. if you clean the `data logs` directory.